# Printing to Google Spreadsheet chat via script / Logging values visible for all users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to use the Google Scripts API in a way that the execution of a script can write text to the chat menu of a Google Spreadsheet? To be clear, I don't mean a msgBox, neither an alert, nor a toast, but the actual chat window, that users of the spreadsheet can use to chat with one another.

I didn't find a way to do so given the [Google Scripting Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet), but maybe there is some way.

The use case is as following: There are multiple active users of the spreadsheet of which each regularly encounters a situation, that they have to use a script to calculate a value that should be shown to all users. The users shouldn't have to switch the sheet and shouldn't have to do any active interaction like closing a popup that shows the calculated value. The value should just be logged, instantly visible to all users of the spreadsheet and because of the fact, that each user can have to generate a value multiple times during a session, it should also not just be filling cell A1 with the calculated value in everyones sheet, but rather be useable as an actual log (like it would be in the chat window). The values don't have to be stored permanently and users that open the sheet after a value has been printed don't have to be able to see that value anymore.

Comment: I've never seen such a functionality.  I don't think it exists. You could write a web app in the sidebar to replace the chat. You'd probably have to sample the server from the client to keep everyone up to date.

Comment: Hi ! What about logging these changing values in a specific column of your sheet? Would that fit your needs? Or have you consider taking use of comments in specific cells of the sheet? Let me know if any of these options would fit you situation, thanks! :D